# Data inserting into Master Table after Partition

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a database table on postgres database that is more than 1 TB and has around 2 billions of records. So, I decided to partition the table based on "timestamp" column.

-- Step 1. Create Partition Tables

```
CREATE TABLE bigtable_y2019 (
    CHECK (timestamp >= '2019-01-01' AND timestamp < '2020-01-01')
) INHERITS (bigtable);

CREATE TABLE bigtable_y2020 (
    CHECK (timestamp >= '2020-01-01' AND timestamp < '2021-01-01')
) INHERITS (bigtable);
```

-- Step 2. Create index on the key column (timestamp)

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX bigtable_y2019_pkey ON bigtable_y2019 USING btree (id);
CREATE INDEX bigtable_y2019_timestamp ON bigtable_y2019 (timestamp);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX bigtable_y2020_pkey ON bigtable_y2020 USING btree (id);
CREATE INDEX bigtable_y2020_timestamp ON bigtable_y2020 (timestamp);
```

-- Step 3. Create Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bigtable_insert_trigger()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
IF (NEW.timestamp >= '2020-01-01' AND NEW.timestamp < '2021-01-01') THEN
        INSERT INTO bigtable_y2020 VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSIF (NEW.timestamp >= '2019-01-01' AND NEW.timestamp < '2020-01-01') THEN
        INSERT INTO bigtable_y2019 VALUES (NEW.*);    
    ELSE
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Date out of range.  Fix the bigtable_insert_trigger() function!';
    END IF;
    -- My understanding was this should have prevented inserting data into master table
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

-- Step 4. Enable Trigger ON BEFORE INSERT EVENT and execute the function

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_bigtable_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON bigtable FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION bigtable_insert_trigger();
```

-- Step 5. Set enable_partition_pruning and contstraint_exclusion to ON

```
SET enable_partition_pruning = ON;
SET constraint_exclusion = ON;
```

These above steps insert the record on not only child table but on Parent table as well which I am trying to avoid.

So, I tried to create another trigger for AFTER INSERT event to remove the parent table. It is not a best approach but my work around to see how it is working.

--Since, RETURN NULL in tripdetail_insert_trigger is not avoiding insertion on master table, I have created a workaround to remove that record from master table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bigtable_mastertable_record_delete_trigger()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
DELETE FROM ONLY bigtable WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER delete_bigtable_mastertable_record_trigger AFTER INSERT ON bigtable FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION bigtable_mastertable_record_delete_trigger();
```

There is sync between parent table and child tables. If record gets inserted into child table so does in parent table and if record gets deleted in either of those, then record gets deleted in another as well.

But, I am trying to insert the new records into corresponding child table based on timestamp and eventually make the parenttable empty which it should be based on the working principles of table partitioning.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? If you really need partitioning, you should use at least 11 (better 12) and use the new declarative partitioning. Forget about inheritance based partitioning. With 12 any insert into the base table will automatically be redirected to the correct partition

Comment: You original set up works for me.  What have you done to conclude that the row is being inserted into both places?  I bet you are mis-interpretting something.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using postgres 11. There is no plan upgrading to 12 yet, so I am trying to make this work on version 11.

Comment: @jjanes I executed insert statement for one record with the year 2020, and I see that the same record exists (they have same id) in both of the tables. I would be happy to clear things more.

Comment: Postgres 11 will also route the row to the correct partition. You should definitely use declarative partitioning, not the (somewhat obsolete) inheritance based partitioning.

Comment: When you issue the select to see it in the master table, did you specify ONLY?  When I do that with your setup, I see it only in the appropriate child table.  It does show up in the master if you don't use ONLY, because that is how inheritance works and indeed is the point.  But I do agree with the horse, you should probably use declarative partitioning instead, which is available in v11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the partitioning capabilities of PostgreSQL 11, the parent table will only be a definition and will NOT contain any entries. See the section Declarative Partitioning here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE

If you have an existing database following steps are needed:

1. Rename old table

   > ALTER TABLE bigtable RENAME TO bigtable_pre_partitioning;
2. Create partitioned table (define structure, index, range key)

   > CREATE TABLE bigtable (
   >   id         int not null,
   >   logdate         date not null
   >   ) PARTITION BY RANGE (logdate);
3. Create partition

   > CREATE TABLE bigtable_2020_01 PARTITION OF bigtable
   >   FOR VALUES FROM ('2020-01-01') TO ('2020-02-01');
4. Create another partition

   > CREATE TABLE bigtable_2020_02 PARTITION OF bigtable
   >   FOR VALUES FROM ('2020-02-01') TO ('2020-03-01');
5. Attach old partition (this takes a very long time depending on how much data you have)

   > ALTER TABLE bigtable ATTACH PARTITION bigtable_pre_partitioning
   >   FOR VALUES FROM (MINVALUE) TO ('2020-01-01');
6. Now you can insert entries directly into the bigtable parent and they will land in the correct partition.

   > INSERT INTO bigtable ...

Some things to note:

- The primary key must contain the range key
- If you create an index on the parent table -> new partition will inherit it
- If you create a constraint on the parent table -> new partition will inherit it
- You can create a default table where all entries land if you have no matching partition range

Hope this helps. The article linked above contains a section about best practices what is quite helpful.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. This totally works. Sorry for my late response though, as we were going through some review process before we implement these.

Comment: When I'm at step 5. (of your answer) I'm getting ```[23514] ERROR: partition constraint is violated by some row``` . Why is that? My database partition by range(<is a datetime column>) as your example.

Comment: Happy to hear that it worked Bikash Lama. :)
Hello @sofs1, the pre_partitioning table must have the same constraints as the new partitioned table. If you describe both tables you should see if the constraints are the same. Does that help you?

Comment: @DanielP. By mistake I added ```partition by range``` in the create partition table. So that was the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect! That's great.

Answer (score 1):

`enable_partition_pruning` was added in PostgreSQL 11.
If you are using PostgreSQL 11, then why don't you use table partition capability in PostgreSQL 11
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-partitioning.html

Comment: Yes, you are right I am using PostgreSQL 11. In fact, that's the documentation that I followed to implement partitioning. All the steps that I have performed are from that link.

Comment: @BikashLama: you followed the examples for inheritance based partitioning, but you should have followed those for the (relatively new) declarative partitioning: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE

Comment: Try the Declarative Partitioning in PostgreSQL 11.  

```
CREATE TABLE measurement (
    logdate         date not null,
    peaktemp        int,
    unitsales       int
) PARTITION BY RANGE (logdate);
```

Comment: Yeah, I had tried that earlier with the following steps:
```CREATE TABLE bigtable_y2020 (LIKE bigtable INCLUDING DEFAULTS INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS);
ALTER TABLE bigtable_y2020 ADD CONSTRAINT bigtabley2019constraint CHECK ( timestamp >= '2020-01-01' AND timestamp < '2021-01-01' );
ALTER TABLE bigtable ATTACH PARTITION bigtable_y2020 FOR VALUES FROM ('2020-01-01') TO ('2021-01-01');```
But I get this error:
```SQL Error [42P17]: ERROR: table "bigtable" is not partitioned```
And as per documentation: it says "It is not possible to turn a regular table into a partitioned table or vice versa"

Comment: So, maybe the only option left is to create copy of table with partition enabled then copy the data and create partitions as per suggested in this thread?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57039108/attach-partition-list-to-existing-table-in-postgres-11