# Partition in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ddl, database-partitioning

everyone!

Im new in postgresql and try to partition the existing table.
So I want something like

`alter table t1 partition by range (c_date);`

but get a syntax error at or near partition.
Also I tried to add `start from` and get same error too.
Can I partition table without create new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can not change an existing non-partitioned table to a partitioned table, for more details:

> [Attach partition LIST to existing table in postgres 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57039108/attach-partition-list-to-existing-table-in-postgres-11)

If you want more information about migrating an existing table to a partitioned table, you can read this:

> https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106014/how-to-partition-existing-table-in-postgres